# How to save a txt file to a predetermined location in vb 2010?

Tags: vb.net

Hi i have a textbox which displays a bunch of names on it. The names are within a string called "strNames". I'm trying to have a save button which saves the names as a txt file in a predetermined location. Here is the code for the save button. It creates the file but without the list of names. please help!

Comment: What is `strNames`? A TextBox or a String?

Comment: A string              Dim strName(9) As String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that your `strNames` is an array of strings then you could use [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx), no need to use a StreamWriter here

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    File.WriteAllLines("C:\Test.txt", strNames)
End Sub
```

This has an advantage against the StreamWriter approach if you don't need particular processing to your input array before writing it to file, no foreach around the array strings and also you don't need to encapsulate the StreamWriter in a Using statement to ensure a proper release of the system resources

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to the file and then call Close() on the StreamWriter

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim w As IO.StreamWriter
    w = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Test.txt")
    ' strNames is an array so you have to iterate through the array and write each element
    For Each item As String In strNames
        w.WriteLine(item)
    Next
    w.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I typed in the code but it still doesn't work. All that comes up in the txt file is " System.string []"

Comment: Is your textbox a mult-line text box?

Comment: Yes it is a multiline

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use Try/Catch blocks in case any exception occurs during accessing and writing to the file.
Also, when you use resources such as Files, make sure to properly dispose of the object that's connected to the resource. Using the 'Using' statement is a great and safe way to do that. Here's an example of both in action.

```
Sub WriteToFile()
  Dim strNames As String() = {"John", "Jimmy", "Joe"}
  Try
    Using oWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\testFile.txt")
      For Each strName As String In strNames
        oWriter.WriteLine(strName)
      Next
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
    HandleException(ex)
  End Try
End Sub
```